# New fragment on button click from another fragment?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-fragments

can anyone point me in the right direction and tell me what I'm doing wrong?

I have here a fragment with a button. When the button is pressed, it needs to replace the current fragment and load a new one. I've figured how to go from Fragment to Activity, and Activity to Fragment, just not Fragment to Fragment. I'm aware this question has been asked a few times but I'm just so new I couldn't figure it out myself.

```
public class FragmentName extends Fragment {

    public FragmentName() {
        // Required empty public constructor

    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_name, container, false);

        Button ID = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.buttonID);
        ID.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                FragmentName NAME = new FragmentName();
                fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.main_container, NAME);
                fragmentTransaction.commit();
            }
        });
        return rootView;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are not initialising the FragmentManager. Without FragmentManager it is not possible to replace,update,create any fragment. Beacuse it is responsible replace or deleting any fragment. Hope this will help.

```
public class FragmentName extends Fragment {

public FragmentName() {
    // Required empty public constructor

}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_name, container, false);

    Button ID = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.buttonID);
    ID.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        FragmentName NAME = new FragmentName();
      fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.main_container, NAME);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();

        }
    });
    return rootView;
  }
}
```

Comment: Stupid mistake on my part. Thanks!